# Meteor - Recursive function in template onrendered

Tags: function, templates, recursion, meteor

I am getting an error with the following code:

```
Template.crowd.onRendered(function () {

var zecsec = 0;
var hours = 1;
var mints = 34;
var seconds = 52;

function chronometer() {
    zecsec += 1;

    // set seconds
    if(zecsec > 0) {
      zecsec = 0;
      seconds += 1;
    }

    // set minutes
    if(seconds > 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      mints += 1;
    }

    // set hours
    if(mints > 59) {
      seconds = 0;
      mints = 0;
      hours += 1;
    }

    $('.chrono').html(hours + 'h&nbsp;' + mints + 'min&nbsp;' + seconds + 's');
    setTimeout("chronometer()", 1000);
}
chronometer(); });
```

The problems comes when I call recursively chronometer function:

```
setTimeout("chronometer()", 1000);
```

Meteor returns the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chronometer is not defined
```

Should I put such custom code in template `onRendered` function ? I also tried to include it directly in template with `<script>` tags and so far it works ! But isn't it a bad practice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about recursion, you just have to pass the function reference to setTimeout not a string:

```
setTimeout(chronometer, 1000);
```

Comment: ... thank you, it was very stupid of me ... 
I got a second question (and hope it is not as bad as my first one), everytime I navigate out of the page and come back, the chronometer function is duplicated which results in odd ui visualisation. Should I kill the function when I navigate away from template ?

Comment: I think I found my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31871785/meteor-how-to-clearinterval-ondestroyed-created-in-onrendered - have a good day ;)